# What is 0[p] doing?

Tags: c

What is the following C code doing?

```
int i;
int* p = &i;
0[p] = 42;
```

I would have though that this would not event compile. But it even executes without a segmentation fault. So I wonder what strange use of the `[]` operator I have missed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **C Standard** defined the operator `[]` this way:

Whatever `a` and `b` are `a[b]` is considred as `*((a)+(b))`

And that's why `0[p] == *(0 + p) == *(p + 0) == p[0]` which is the first element of the array.

Answer (score 9):

`0[p]` is equivalent to `p[0]`. Both are converted as

```
0[p] = *(0+p) and p[0] = *(p+0)
```

From above statements both are equal.

Answer (score 7):

```
0[p]
```

in `0[p] = 42;`

is equivalent to `p[0]`

`+` operation is commutative and we have:

```
p[0] == *(p + 0) == *(0 + p) == 0[p]
```